# Using a system variable with spaces without truncating prematurely

Tags: windows, environment-variables, cmd.exe

I need to do something similar to this:

```
dir > %USERNAME%.txt
```

But what I get is that if the filename has a SPACE(" ") in it, then the name is cut there.

I know that if I do this:

```
set tmp=%USERNAME%.txt
```

I have the desired filename.

How can I add the quotes (") using my original syntax? Is there another solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest you to try

`dir > "%USERNAME%.txt"`